# how to keep my abbrevs table files separate?

Tags: abbrev, ispell, flyspell

I'd like to maintain several distinct `abbrevs` files for different types of abbreviation expansions.

I have this:

```
(read-abbrev-file "~/Dropbox/elisp/main-abbrevs-file.abbrev_defs")
(read-abbrev-file "~/Dropbox/elisp/own-separate-abbrevs.abbrev_defs")
```

But what happens is the all the abbrevs in my other separate abbrevs files get automatically sucked into and added to my main abbrevs file, which I don't want.

I can do `(setq save-abbrevs nil)`... but this disables other functionality that I want, which is to [automatically learn my typos and add them to my main abbrevs file](http://endlessparentheses.com/ispell-and-abbrev-the-perfect-auto-correct.html)—functionality which seems to require `(setq save-abbrevs t)`.

How can I get it so that Emacs automatically learns new abbrevs from ispell, but still allow me to keep a separate abbrevs file with abbrevs that don't get automatically added to my main abbrevs file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling a `(set (make-local-variable 'abbrev-file-name) 'My-current-abbrev-file)` preceding this `read-abbrev-file` should help.

Comment: Like this? `(set (make-local-variable 'abbrev-file-name) '("~/Dropbox/elisp/own-ab brevs.abbrev_defs"))`

Comment: @PeterSalazar Try this: (set (make-local-variable 'abbrev-file-name) (expand-file-name "~/Dropbox/elisp/own-abbrevs.abbrev_defs"))